# AWS Route 53 not resolving to Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Trying to get a domain to point Elastic IP attached to a EC2 instance. The EC2 is reachable by the IP address; using the domain name returns an error stating `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`. Any assistance is appreciated.

[image: AWS Route 53 settings]
[image: whois response]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SOA record appears to be broken. I am a little bit puzzled here - AWS usually creates and configures it properly for you and most of the time should not touch it. Yours seems to be just copied from an example instead. But you need to actually replace it's parts with proper values.

First part (ns-2048.awsdns-64.net), should be replaced with one of the values from NS record above it. And hostmaster.example.com address should be replaced with actual hostmaster e-mail (e.g. hostmaster.davidjeddy.com, though I'd recommend keeping it at amazon as awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com).

For example, ns-116.awsdns-14.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. an then the following numbers should be fine. Mind dots and spaces.

More details can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html#SOArecords. Though I suspect you have already seen it.